# How I have scroll in bar chart ? [Echarts]

Tags: css, angular, echarts

I'm using echart to create bar I have this question:

I want to have fixed height and width to only show 5 rows when its more than 5 it have vertical scroll I tried to do it in html but the numbers/ xAxis it disappear and only appears when the user pull the scroll down so I need to make it in echart

```
option = {
barWidth: '30%',
barCategoryGap :'10%',
title: {
    text: 'test',
},
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    axisPointer: {
        type: 'shadow'
    }
},

grid: {
    left: '7%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '40%',
    containLabel: true
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    boundaryGap: [0, 0.01]
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Web', 'Web', 'web', 'web', 'web','web', 'web', 'web']
},
series: [
    {
        name: 'test',
        type: 'bar',
        data: [ 100, 80,30,50, 70, 100, 80,30]
    },

]
```

};

Answer (score 5):

To make the chart scrollable, add this to your chart option configuration.

> You can get the scrollbar to appear on the right with this configuration.

```
 dataZoom: [
      {
        type: 'slider',
        yAxisIndex: 0,
        zoomLock: true,
        width: 10,
        right: 10,
        start: 25,
        end: 100,
        handleSize: 20,

      },
 ]
```

> Using this configuration, you can use the mouse cursor to move the chart.

```
dataZoom:[ {
        type: 'inside',
        id: 'insideY',
        yAxisIndex: 0,
        start: 95,
        end: 100,
        zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
        moveOnMouseMove: true,
        moveOnMouseWheel: true
      }]
```

By using this **yAxisIndex** key, you can place the scrollbar on the y-axis, and by using this **xAxisIndex** key, you can place scrollbar on the x-axis and Other properties can be configured based on that.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, check datazoom option.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-simple
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/#chart-type-dataZoom